# Media Recording: java.lang.RuntimeException: start failed in API level 26

Tags: android

I am working on records a phone calls.
The following code works correctly until API level 25.

But when recording an incoming call, an ***exception("IllegalStateException")*** occurs only in the **API level 26**.

```
01-01 19:27:08.715 5446-5446/com.app E/MediaRecorder: start failed: -38
01-01 19:27:08.716 5446-5446/com.app W/System.err: java.lang.IllegalStateException
01-01 19:27:08.717 5446-5446/com.app W/System.err:     at android.media.MediaRecorder.start(Native Method)
01-01 19:27:08.718 5446-5446/com.app W/System.err:     at com.app.CallRecorderManager.startRecording(CallRecorderManager.java:62)
01-01 19:27:08.718 5446-5446/com.app W/System.err:     at com.app.PhoneListener.onCallStateChanged(PhoneListener.java:59)
01-01 19:27:08.719 5446-5446/com.app W/System.err:     at android.telephony.PhoneStateListener$1.handleMessage(PhoneStateListener.java:324)
01-01 19:27:08.721 5446-5446/com.app W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
01-01 19:27:08.721 5446-5446/com.app W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
01-01 19:27:08.722 5446-5446/com.app W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
01-01 19:27:08.722 5446-5446/com.app W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
01-01 19:27:08.723 5446-5446/com.app W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
01-01 19:27:08.724 5446-5446/com.app W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
```

This is my code :

```
    public void startRecording(String outputPath) throws Exception {
    File director = new File(outputPath);
    if (!director.exists()) {
        if (!director.mkdirs()) {
            throw new IOException("Can not create directory ");
        }
    }
    myAudioRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
    myAudioRecorder.reset();
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= 22) {
        myAudioRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.VOICE_CALL);
    } else {
        myAudioRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
    }
    myAudioRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
    myAudioRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
    fileName = outputPath + "/" + Filename();
    myAudioRecorder.setOutputFile(fileName);
    try {
            myAudioRecorder.prepare();
            myAudioRecorder.start();
            myAudioRecorder.setOnErrorListener(errorListener);

    } catch (Exception e){
        throw new Exception(e.getMessage());
    }
    }
```

Comment: What line follow the `java.lang.RuntimeException: start failed.` ?
Something like `at android.media.MediaRecorder.start(Native Method)` ?
Edit : Can you paste **lines** that are folowing the exception ? Looking for someting like `at com.liucveikis.beatboxjam.SoundRecorderActivity.startRecording(SoundRecorderActivity.java:101)`

Comment: @ThomasMary I updated the question with stack trace.